# Configure printer-specific settings in Python -Win32

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm working on a project to automate the task of printing some photos.  My printer is an R300 (for now), and there are extra settings such as "quality" where I can specify "Best photo".  There is also another setting where I can specify the paper type.

Are there ways to specify these settings programatically via python?  I'm currently using the Python win32 api.

Comment: Have a look at `win32print`, especially `GetPrinter`, check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5555453/321973)