# How to change printer preference settings using python

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm new to python and want to change the printer preference settings. I'm using win32print library and need to change PyDEVMODE Object properties given on link http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyDEVMODE.html as per requirement.But facing problem in crating object.

I have tried this- [Python win32print changing advanced printer options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555453/python-win32print-changing-advanced-printer-options)

getting error  "name 'pDevModeObj' is not defined"

```
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}  
pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter('300LN1', PRINTER_DEFAULTS)  
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2)  
pDevModeObj.Orientation = 2  
properties["pDevMode"]=pDevModeObj   
win32print.SetPrinter(pHandle,2,properties,0)
```

Comment: Have you tried `pDevModeObj = properties['pDevMode']`?

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see the changes made in orientation after running the script. It is same as before i.e. Auto portrait/landscape @MarkRansom

Comment: Sorry, the only time I've tried to change printer properties it was from C++ where these things are much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This code will obviously give error.

As you are using `pDevModeObj` before its creation.
Even in next line, you are not assigning value to `pDevModeObj` but rather assigning variable `pDevModeObj` to `properties["pDevMode"]`, which does not work in Python.

The fix to your existing solution would be:

```
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}  
pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter('300LN1', PRINTER_DEFAULTS)  
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2)
pDevModeObj = properties["pDevMode"]
pDevModeObj.Orientation = 2  
win32print.SetPrinter(pHandle,2,properties,0)
win32print.ClosePrinter(pHandle)
```