# Adjust advanced printer options using Python win32print programmatically

Tags: python-3.x

I am able to adjust properties like PaperLength, PaperWidth and Orientation using below code snippet. But I am unable to find a way to do something similar with respect to print speed and darkness adjustments.

```
import win32print


pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(str(self.printername.get()))
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2) 
pDevModeObj = properties["pDevMode"]
pDevModeObj.Orientation = DMORIENT_PORTRAIT
pDevModeObj.PaperLength = int(Length) # Variable
pDevModeObj.PaperWidth = int(Width) # Variable
```

I have checked a similar post but it has not helped fully.
[Python win32print changing advanced printer options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555453/python-win32print-changing-advanced-printer-options)

Comment: `win32print` is not defined  which module does it come from ?

Comment: win32print module I am importing for this.

Comment: i have modded the question to add this line, but there are still undefined variables `DMORIENT_PORTRAIT`, `Length` & `Width`....  where are these from and what are they ?

Comment: it looks like a class needs to be instantiated. to help users answer, please ask the question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example